# Deleting files ending with 2 digits in linux

Tags: linux, bash, glob

In my folder, I want to delete the files that ends with 2 digits (10, 11, 12, etc.)

What I've tried is

```
rm [0-9]*
```

but it seems like it doesn't work.

What is the right syntax of doing this?

Comment: rm -r *[0-9] should work.

Comment: `rm -i *[0-9][0-9]` as long as you don't mind files ending with three digits being removed; `rm -i *[!0-9][0-9][0-9]` if you do mind the three-digit files being removed, and if Bash history expansion doesn't get in the way.

Comment: @AshishSrivastavaL that removes files that end with just one digit, too

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  You are right, it works

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're right. But how about using something like `*[0-9]{2}`?

Comment: @AshishSrivastava: Have you tried it?  Which `shopt` option(s) did you set to get it to work? (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching, https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

Your requirement is a bit ambiguous.  However, you can use:

```
rm -i *[0-9][0-9]
```

as long as you don't mind files ending with three digits being removed.  If you do mind the three-digit files being removed, use:

```
rm -i *[!0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

(assuming Bash history expansion doesn't get in the way).  Note that if you have file names consisting of just 2 digits, those will not be removed; that would require:

```
rm -i [0-9][0-9]
```

#### Caution!

The `-i` option is for interactive.  It is generally a bad idea to experiment with globbing and `rm` commands because you can do a lot of damage if you get it wrong.  However, you can use other techniques to neutralize the danger, such as:

```
echo *[!0-9][0-9]
```

which echoes all the file names, or:

```
printf '%s\n' *[!0-9][0-9]
```

which lists the file names one per line.  Basically, be cautious when experimenting with file deletion — don't risk making a mistake unless you know you have good backups readily available.  Even then, it is better not to need to use them

See also the GNU Bash manual on:

- [Pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) — which notes you might be able to use `^` in place of `!`.
- [The `shopt` built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
rm [0-9]*
```

means remove **all the files** that start with a digit. The range within `[]` is expanded single time.

Whereas you intend to remove files ending with double digit, so command should be

```
rm *[0-9][0-9]
```

If you have some file extension, the command should be modified as

```
rm *[0-9][0-9]* or
rm *[0-9][0-9].ext
```

where `ext` is the extension like `txt`